Cron Jobs kubernetes with quarkus
I want to run  batches develop with Quarkus on Kubernetes. I would like to use Cron Job Kubernetes. I want to start the pod only for the batch execution time (which can last several minutes). The solution of triggering the batch with an http call is not possible because the call times out.
I have tried @Scheduled annotation or Quartz library. But I want to start pod only time of process and stop after.

You can create a cron container then run the quarkus job on boot then kill the container. You can match the @Scheduler time with the cron time but I dont think it is really necessary, boot run will be enough and easy.
